# R - nested loop alternatives/optimization

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, nested-loops, needleman-wunsch

I'm currently trying to implement an algorithm in R that requires to loop through the rows and columns of a matrix and that for every cell it computes a value based on the value of previously computed cells.

Here is the code that does what I said above, it is a part of the Needleman Wunsch algorithm:

```
    globalSequenceAlignment <- function(seq1, seq2, match, mismatch, gap) {
    
    # splitting the sequences in order to use them as rows and columns names
    seq1_split <- unlist(strsplit(toString(seq1), ""))
    seq2_split <- unlist(strsplit(toString(seq2), ""))
    
    len1 <- length(seq1_split)
    len2 <- length(seq2_split)
    
    # creating the alignment matrix
    alignment_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = len2+1, ncol = len1+1)
    colnames(alignment_matrix) <- c("-", seq1_split)
    rownames(alignment_matrix) <- c("-", seq2_split)
    
    # filling first row and column of the alignment matrix
    for (i in 2:ncol(alignment_matrix)) {
      alignment_matrix[1,i] <- (alignment_matrix[1,i]+(i-1))*(gap)
    }
    
    for (j in 2:nrow(alignment_matrix)) {
      alignment_matrix[j,1] <- (alignment_matrix[j,1]+(j-1))*(gap)
    }
    
    for (i in 2:ncol(alignment_matrix)) {
      for (j in 2:nrow(alignment_matrix)) {
        
        horizontal_score <- alignment_matrix[j,i-1] + gap
        vertical_score <- alignment_matrix[j-1,i] + gap
        
        if (colnames(alignment_matrix)[i] == rownames(alignment_matrix)[j]) {
          diagonal_score <- alignment_matrix[j-1,i-1] + match
        } else {
          diagonal_score <- alignment_matrix[j-1,i-1] + mismatch
        }
        
        scores <- c(horizontal_score, vertical_score, diagonal_score)
        
        alignment_matrix[j,i] <- max(scores)
        
      }
    }
    
    
    return(alignment_matrix)
  
}

a <- 'GAATC'
b <- 'CATACG'

globalSequenceAlignment(a, b, 10,-5,-4)
```

Using this code I get the result that I want.
The problem is that with matrices with dimensions grater than 500x500 the nested loops become way too slow (running this code with a 500x500 matrix takes more or less 2 minutes).

I know that *apply functions could improve this but I couldn't achieve to use them since for computing each cell it requires that the previous ones have been computed yet.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result using *apply functions or a way to vectorize this type of code so that it's more rapid in R.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I edited with a function that gives you the result I need, the crucial and slow part is only the nested loop.

Comment: Hi. FYI that the Bioconductor BioStrings has a Needleman Wunsch function in the `PairwiseAlignments` function https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biostrings/inst/doc/PairwiseAlignments.pdf

Comment: And the CRAN ftrCOOL package has a `needleman` function. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ftrCOOL/ftrCOOL.pdf Which might give you what you want, or the source code might give you ideas.

Comment: Yes, I know there are already functions for Needleman Wunsch algorithm, I was trying to reimplement this function for a project. I'll try looking for the source code of the Needleman function of ftrCOOL, thank you! EDIT: I looked at the Needleman function but the source code is almost the same as mine so I think the performance issue would be the same.

Comment: I've tried a few ideas, and none panned out: `compiler:cmpfun()` no faster; simplified loop, no faster; using `ifelse`, slower; attempting to use `outer()` and an anonymous function - incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks for trying out, I'm starting to think that the only way for speeding this up "in R" is to use Rcpp to loop through the matrix with C++ for loops. I will maybe try to do this even if it was my last chance since I don't know C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone would ever need this I wrote my own solution to this problem using the package Rcpp. The runtime, from about 3 minutes for sequences of 500 characters, is now about 0.3s.

I post here the code for the part of the two nested loops that you can see in the text of the question, hope that will be useful for someone.

```
library(Rcpp)

rcppFunction('IntegerMatrix rcpp_compute_matrices(IntegerMatrix Am, StringMatrix Dm,
                                                  StringVector seq1, StringVector seq2,
                                                  int gap, int miss, int match) {

    int nrow = Am.nrow(), ncol = Am.ncol();

    for (int i = 1; i < nrow; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < ncol; j++) {
        int vertical_score = Am(i-1, j) + gap;
        int horizontal_score = Am(i, j-1) + gap;
        int diagonal_score = 0;
        if (seq1[j-1] == seq2[i-1]) {
          diagonal_score = Am(i-1, j-1) + match;
        }
        else {
          diagonal_score = Am(i-1, j-1) + miss;
        }

        IntegerVector score = {vertical_score, horizontal_score, diagonal_score};

        int max_score = max(score);

        Am(i, j) = max_score;

        }
    }
    return Am;
}')
```